# How to create Undo and Redo value functionality from input tag in Angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, logic

I want to create a functionality which undo and redo value from input tag in angular. What I supposed to do is as follows if I enter **Hello** in input:

1. *click undo button*: show **hell**
2. *click undo button*: show **hel**
3. *click redo button*: show **hell**
4. *click redo button*: show **hello**

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do in your .ts:

```
  inputValue: string = '';
  inputStates: string[] = [];
  undoStats: number = 0;

  onChanges(change) {
    this.inputStates.push(change);
    this.undoStats = 0;
  }

  undo() {
    this.undoStats++;
    this.inputValue = this.inputStates[this.inputStates.length - (this.undoStats + 1)];
  }

  redo() {
    if (this.undoStats > 0) this.undoStats--;
    if (this.undoStats >= 0)
      this.inputValue = this.inputStates[this.inputStates.length - (this.undoStats + 1)];
  }
```

and in html:

```
<div>
  <input
    type="text"
    [(ngModel)]="inputValue"
    (ngModelChange)="onChanges($event)"
  />
  <br />
  <button (click)="undo()">Undo</button><button (click)="redo()">Redo</button>
</div>
```

You'll only need to find a point at which you'll clear `this.inputStates` (like onSubmit or something like that).

Comment: Thanks alot. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: here is working demo https://jsfiddle.net/nwafme4y/2/ . Note :- demo source written with Pure JavaScript

Comment: here is more simplified working demo https://jsfiddle.net/ntp1e9o8/ . Note :- demo source written with Pure JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

There is the functionality already present by the system in input. You can try out the control z button and control y button.

If you want to create your own by then you have to add the mapping of user input fields and values and listen to the undo and redo events and based on that do the undo and redo by going up and down the array